# Create a tree using numbers of h1...h6 tags in a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tree

I've been struggling to find a solution for this for a few hours. I've made some attempts and scratched them, my closest attempt is at the end of this question..

Assume I wish to build a table of contents using `h1`...`h6` tags, I don't have any nesting using divs, etc. The tag is what informs the table of contents if it is a parent or child.

For example, a `h1` then a `h2` means the `h2` is a child of the `h1`.

Lets assume we have an array of elements:

```
// omitting other properties like 'text', etc for brevity.
[{ tag: 2 }, { tag: 2 }, { tag: 3 }, { tag: 3 }, { tag: 4 }, { tag: 2 }]
```

This would represent the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <h2>
    <h2>
    <h3>
    <h3>
    <h4>
    <h2>
</div>
```

And we are after a tree that looks like this:

```
[{
    tag: 2
}, {
    tag: 2
    children: [{
        tag: 3
    }, {
        tag: 3,
        children: [{
            tag: 4
        }]
    }]
}, {
    tag: 2
}]
```

It shouldn't be too difficult, but I just can't wrap my head around it.
Instead of a parent reference (as most other questions have), I am strictly using the number value to signify if its a parent.

- If it's less, its a parent
- If it's equal, it's a sibling
- If it's greater, it's a child

Here's the code I've come up with that works but only in very limited circumstances. For example, if there is a sibling after the last element, it doesn't work.

Thank you!

```
//Loop through the array backwards
let newArr = [];
let tempArr = [];
while (arr.length) {    
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        newArr.unshift(arr.pop())
    } else {
        let item = arr.pop();

        if (tempArr.length == 0) {
            tempArr.push(item);
            item = arr.pop();
        }

        //Check if the items tag is equal to the tempArrs last item tag
        if (item.tag == tempArr[tempArr.length - 1].tag) {
            tempArr.push(item)
        } else if (item.tag < tempArr[tempArr.length - 1].tag) {



            item.children = tempArr;

            //there might be something in newArr...
            if (newArr.length && newArr[0].tag > item.tag) {
                item.children.push(newArr.pop());
            }

            newArr.unshift(item)
            tempArr = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could it start on `tag: 2` and contain `tag: 1`? or different asked, is the first tag always the smallest (greatest) tag?

Comment: Yeah, the first tag will always be the smallest, at the moment I'm assuming `h1` would not be considered due to the reason of there being only 1 `h1` tag per article (usually), however a user might start their headings at h1 in which case an algorithm would ideally allow `h1` through `h6`.

Comment: In other words, if h1 were allowed it would allow h2 children, those h2 children allowing h3 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper array for the levels and take an offset for starting tag (assuming no smaller/parent tags are available).

```js
var array = [{ tag: 2 }, { tag: 2 }, { tag: 3 }, { tag: 3 }, { tag: 4 }, { tag: 2 }],
    offset = -array[0].tag;
    result = [],
    levels = [{ children: result }];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    levels[o.tag + offset].children = levels[o.tag + offset].children || [];
    levels[o.tag + offset].children.push(levels[o.tag + offset + 1] = o);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi, I've marked as accepted answer because it works. However, I really don't quite understand it. I've annotated it (and modified it slightly) here: https://pastebin.com/pucgzCiX

Can you please let me know if my annotations are correct?
Then I'd like to know how you determined the logic for the offset? Especially that it must be negative? Then, how did you determine the expression `o.tag + offset + 1`?

Thanks! This answer is so simple and ingenious, but I don't quite understand it.

Comment: the easiest way, to get what is doing, is to omit offset and assume, your tags starts with zero. then assume, that every node has a children array which is the same as the next level, that is ` + 1`. the `levles` array contains all alst nodes and their children for the next level. `offset` normalize `tag`, and takes the sum to a zero based index for the array.